# IMAP allows creation of multiple mail boxes or folders in the mail box?

Tags: smtp, imap

   IMAP4 provides the following extra features

   User can

    check header prior to downloading

   Search contents of email for a string before downloading

   Partially download emails

   Create, rename or delete mailboxes on mail server

   Create hierarchy of mailboxes in a folder for storage

LAST TWO POINTS ??

one user one mail box right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMAP uses the word **mailbox** like everyone else uses the word **folder**.  Just treat those last two lines as if they read:

- Create, rename or delete **folders** on mail server
- Create hierarchy of **folders** in a folder for storage

Comment: @user287745 That means IMAP lets users create many **folders** within their mailbox.  It's just that the [IMAP RFC](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501) refers to folders using the word "mailboxes", which makes things very confusing.

Comment: @user287745 From the RFC: `IMAP4rev1 permits manipulation of mailboxes (remote message folders) in a way that is functionally equivalent to local folders.`